# ikev2 vpn cant connect to own server via vpn connection win10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, port, strongswan

I just setup a strongswan ikev2 vpn server. On the same server I host a http software on port 8123.

I am currently on a locked down network with only a few open ports. Using the vpn I can connect to every server on every port. Now to my problem:

Using win10 with vpn, I can connect to everything exept my own server on ports that are previosly blocked (8123). I tried a few things:

1. Tried to connect to a blocked site with blocked port on random
   server.
2. Activate vpn connection to server1 and tried the same again with success.
3. Tried to connect to server1 via http with port 8123 without success.

and also

1. Tried the same as above except with server2.
2. Tried to connect to server1 via http with port 8123 with success.

So it seems that I can access everything except my own server on a port that is normaly blocked on this network (port 80 or 443 works).

The strange thing is (How I now that this is a win 10 problem) if I connect to the same network with my android phone and make a vpn connection with server1 and also try to connect to port 8123 on server1 it works.

What is wrong with windows 10?

Comment: I think [Windows excludes the physical address of the VPN server from the VPN](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/WindowsClients#Accessing-the-VPN-server-via-VPN). You have to assign a second IP address to it (could be from a private range and assigned to _lo_, just must be part of the VPN's traffic selector so the client actually tunnels traffic to it).

Comment: okey but how exactly can I do this? whats the easiest wy?

Comment: What's unclear?

Comment: I dont know how I can do that. How can I assign a second ip?

Comment: Manually via `ip addr add ...`, permanently depending on the network configuration of your distribution (e.g. via `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian). Read the man pages for more details.